# django getting distinct records in table seems to choose random row

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a table that contains the pricing data for the cards and I am trying to get the pricing data for distinct cards by `card_id` but this seems to select the row at random. I would like to get the latest `datetime` pricing data for each card `card_id`.

Table:

| id | nonfoil | foil | datetime | card_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "fb7fbcdc" | 0.20 | 0.49 | "2021-10-11 10:03:51.943603+01" | "00302342" |
| "d0d6f491" | 0.10 | 0.49 | "2021-10-11 10:01:09.916438+01" | "00302342" |
| "bfdca73b" | 0.03 | 0.04 | "2021-10-11 10:03:51.907601+01" | "012e0b83" |
| "33c7aeae" | 0.10 | 0.04 | "2021-10-11 10:01:09.875894+01" | "012e0b83" |
| "94ca3324" | 0.10 | 0.04 | "2021-10-11 10:01:09.961261+01" | "0307f37b" |
| "2e992a8d" | 0.03 | 0.04 | "2021-10-11 10:03:51.988602+01" | "0307f37b" |

I currently am getting the pricing data using the following code:

```py
pricing_cards.objects.filter(card_id__rarity='mythic').values_list('nonfoil', flat=True).distinct('card_id'),
```

For example this is returning:

| id | nonfoil | foil | datetime | card_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "d0d6f491" | 0.10 | 0.49 | "2021-10-11 10:01:09.916438+01" | "00302342" |
| "bfdca73b" | 0.03 | 0.04 | "2021-10-11 10:03:51.907601+01" | "012e0b83" |
| "94ca3324" | 0.10 | 0.04 | "2021-10-11 10:01:09.961261+01" | "0307f37b" |

But I would like it to return:

| id | nonfoil | foil | datetime | card_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "fb7fbcdc" | 0.20 | 0.49 | "2021-10-11 10:03:51.943603+01" | "00302342" |
| "bfdca73b" | 0.03 | 0.04 | "2021-10-11 10:03:51.907601+01" | "012e0b83" |
| "94ca3324" | 0.10 | 0.04 | "2021-10-11 10:01:09.961261+01" | "0307f37b" |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

`pricing_cards.objects.filter(card_id__rarity='mythic').order_by('card_id', '-datetime').distinct('card_id').values_list('nonfoil', flat=True)`